How can I update the object value inside the list and make it reactive in Get Flutter
I have a list of the Map [{name: 'john', commented: 20} , ....]
controller
    .nameList[controller
            .nameList
            .indexWhere(
                (item) => item['name'] == name)]
        ['commented']
    .value = newValue;

But, it does not update the value correctly. Is there a proper way to update the object Map the List?

Try to wrap 'commented' value in RxInt as commented field have to be reactive for updating value. Map list like  [{'name': 'john', 'commented': RxInt(20)},...]

  int index = nameList.indexWhere((item) => item['name'] == name);

  if (index != -1)
    {
    // found
    nameList[index]['commented'] = newValue;
     }
  else
   {
   // NOT FOUND
   }

BTW, what is .value you are referencing in your question? you just can set a new value to commented field like what happened in the if clause.
